# chrome cache removal for single files

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

recently I had to remove my entire cache to be able to view a webpage I was working on. This is fine I guess but it could be improved by removing specific pages from the cache.
the chrome.browsingData.remove, seemingly has no option for indicating individual pages for removal. I was wondering if this could be done externally, but I am not familiar with the chromium code. I was also wondering if there are any planned changes to the chrome.browsingData.remove implementation.
Many thanks

Comment: I want to know this, too. I am using a heavy UI framework, everytime I refresh my js, this UI framework need to be reloaded...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are working on a webpage and wish to avoid caching (btw, it's recommended! :) You can do it today in Chrome DevTools.
Go to Settings (the icon in the bottom-right corner) and click on it.
Then, you will have an option 'disable cache' - mark it and you done.

Just don't forget to return this state when you done working as chrome will be faster with its caching schema.

Comment: That is not quite what I had in mind. Although I am not familiar with the caching scheme that the chrome dev tools uses either. Perhaps it is a confusing tag, but it was the closes one I could find. I am referring to the chrome.browsingData.remove procedure which can be used in an extension to remove, either the entire chrome cache, or none of it.

Comment: This behaviour seems to have changed. See my answer below.

Comment: I will check the more recent answer. of course the single file cache problem is still unsolved...

Comment: new features keep coming :D. also seems in chrome with the devtools open, you can right click the refresh button for extra cache options. thank you google

Answer (score 18):

To remove a single file cache enter its URL into browser and do hard refresh.

Comment: It seems like you can also do it by right-clicking on the row in dev tools network tab and then choose "Clear browser cache"

Comment: @JohanBergens unfortunately that clears all files from the cache, not just the selected file

Answer (score 4):

**Edit 10/Feb/2022:** Access the remote dev tools documentation for a whole suit of tools available to override cached files while developing:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/storage/cache/

If you are attempting to clear HTTP cached data, which was the original question in the post, then the network log is where it is possible. the guide for that is here:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/#load

First find the file then release its cacged content by right clicking:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#clear-cache

Comment: `chrome://cache` doesn't appear to be available any more.

Comment: true, a lot has changed since then, I will update the comment accordingly

Answer (score 3):

To remove **all files** (not single files) while in Chrome DevTools you should click on the Dev Tools settings  then choose
**"Disable cache (while DevTools is open)"**. This was the first option on the page - it is now (as of Chrome 103 in 2022) under network in Preferences.

Note that these settings are not the main Chrome settings, but are specific to Dev Tools.

You can reach DevTools by pressing **F12** while on a web page you want to debug or by pressing **Ctrl-Shift-I**.

**Edited 28 July 2022**

Comment: But this can't move **specific** pages from the cache ?

Comment: No, I don't believe it's possible. It's all or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're building the page dynamically, then during development, you can put a random string at the end of the URL used to load the script.

```
<script src="path/to/script.js?_=<%=Math.random()%>"></script>
```

This will cause a cache miss for that file but will use the cache for everything else (subject to cache-control headers and so on). Just remember to remove the parameter before pushing to prod!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but it's probably what the OP was looking for. To even speed things up further, you would most likely want to `?_=<? filesystem_query_and_find_edit_time_here ?>` which will cache files until they are changed, then renew them and re-cache them.

Answer (score 1):

## UPDATE : `2019, April 20`

Lately, I'm working with `Chrome browser's inbuilt feature - Overrides`.  With this feature, we can write code for `HTML, CSS, JS, etc` directly in the console and see it on the web-page.

[Here's a tutorial that might be helpful](https://umaar.com/dev-tips/162-network-overrides/)

---

## Previous Answer :

### I'm working with [Google Chrome extension `Resource Override`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/resource-override/pkoacgokdfckfpndoffpifphamojphii).

After installing this extension, I'm overriding the resource which I want from the `server` instead of `cache`:

#### STEP #2 : Override the resource which you want fresh from the server:

[image]

#### ⭐`Important Note` - Access the plugin from the `developer-console` instead of the `browser`

#### ⭐⭐ I started with this approach but have moved to approach suggested by Lukas Greblikas in the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48449218/4742733).

Good Luck...

Comment: Using the technique above, with the extension, I couldn’t get the cache to bust on the one file.

Comment: @jktravis, can you check your `network-tab` in the `developer console`?  Ideally, it should have the file with `?v=1` for the file you have _overridden_.