# How to disable cache for some files in google chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, browser-cache, developer-tools

Whenever I run the project, many files(CSS, image and js) requested from a remote server and the project load slowly.

For handling this issue, I unchecked disable cache for all files in the network tab of Chrome DevTools(for caching all files) as follows:

[image: disable cache for some files in chrome]

But the problem started when I need some files(for example test.js,...) don't cache because they change quickly.

How to disable cache for some files(JS, CSS,...)  in google chrome DevTools?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome cache removal for single files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881027/chrome-cache-removal-for-single-files)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to disable cache for specific files.

Maybe the two most common are:

1. The build-in bundle system of .net
2. Add query to your script file name ie:

   ```
   <script src="../whatever/someFile.js?version=1234" />
   //Where version can be a variable taken from web.config or DateTime.Now() of some sort.
   ```

Comment: In spite of good answer but these settings are in code and not in Google Chrome Devtools.

Comment: So perhaps remove the .net and angularjs tags? add browser tag? if you don't want a solution involving changing code @i.Bahrampour

Answer (score -2):

press ctrl+shift+i (devTools>network)
select [Disable cache]

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what the OP was doing before and does not answer the question on only disabling cache for specific files