# Chrome disable cache for one file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm working on a webpage that loads really slow. Since I'm only modifying one file, I was wondering if there was any way to use Chrome's "Disable Cache" feature but only for my specific file.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: You could add a random query parameter like `?qwer` each time

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you just saying to add that in the URL? How would that target a specific file?

Comment: If you add it to the end of a url, chrome should treat it as a separate cache entry, so you would need to change the query param each time. For example, if you are updating some script, you could make it load `.../script.js?t=1526947766736` where the number is a timestamp automatically updated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome cache removal for single files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881027/chrome-cache-removal-for-single-files)