# Disable cache for specific script or stylesheet files in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser-cache, hot-reload

I am developing the web app which uses some external scripts and stylesheets and using Google Chrome for debugging the app.

Certain web pages in the app contains too many external files(Such as script.js and style.css), And while debugging I only need to load the files I have changed from server instead of local browser cache and rest of the files from the cache.

I know about the hot reloading (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) in chrome but it reloads *ALL* the scripts from the server/cdn which takes few extra seconds to load the page and makes debugging annoying.

So how can I force load/disable browser cache for only specific file in Chrome?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chrome cache removal for single files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881027/chrome-cache-removal-for-single-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I want only specific script to be reloaded on page refresh I add to script url timestamp like this:
$v = time();

Every script that has this ?v=... will be reloaded on refresh, others will be read from cache.

Comment: script src="main.js?v=1571665409" type=text/javascript

Comment: Rather than a timestamp, a build version is better, sit still allows caching in a production environment, without changing the code.